# How to convert this Mathematica expression to another, as described here?

Tags: programming, expression-manipulation, logic, expression-construction

I am working on a function of which the core will consist of something like:

```
dta = Reverse[Boole[BooleanTable[{a, b,
      Or[a, b],
      Not[And[Not[a], Not[b]]]
      }]]];
hdr = {
   "P", "Q", "(P \[Or] Q)", "\[Not](\[Not]P \[And] \[Not]Q)"
   };
Grid[
 Prepend[dta, hdr],
 Dividers -> {{False, False, True}, {True, True}}, 
 Spacings -> {1, 1/2},
 Alignment -> Center, FrameStyle -> Gray]
```

If you run this you'll get an idea of what I am working with. At the end of the day this might be helpful for students to self-investigate propositional logic.

My current issue is the following: I would like to translate, convert, ( or whatever it is called ), an expression like

```
  a, b,
  Or[a, b],
  Not[And[Not[a], Not[b]]]
```

which will act as an argument in the function

to

```
 "P", "Q", "(P \[Or] Q)", "\[Not](\[Not]P \[And] \[Not]Q)"
```

Let me explain:

```
letters a,b to P,Q or a,b,c to P,Q,R or a,b,c,d to P,Q,R,S 
Or[a,b] to "(P \[Or] Q)", and so on... including And, Nor, Nand, Not, Implies
```

Would this be, at all, possible? If so, can you give a hint as to how start analyzing the argument? What properties should the function have, and so on?

What have I tried so far?

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[v_] := Module[{},
  HoldForm[v]] /. {a :> P, b :> Q}
```

As you can see I am in trouble with

```
f[Or[a,b]]
```

I don't know how to handle the Or and how to continue from here.

Isn't this quite a challenge?

Comment: `rules = {a -> P, b -> Q, c -> R, d -> S, e -> T};` and then `Apply[Or, {a, b}] /. rules` ? or further use `// TraditionalForm` at the end?

Comment: Thank you. Forget the R,S,T for now. Can you add the Apply to the function f, in some way? That would possibly bring us a step further ? - The intermediate result must be: "(P \[Or] Q)" including double quotes and brackets.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT-1**

I think it is working better now. I have taken the liberty to change a few things that I will explain.

---

First define a utility function:

```
Clear[h];
h[expr_] := Module[{
   rules = MapThread[Rule,
     {CharacterRange["a", "h"],
      CharacterRange["P", "W"]}],
   logicStrings = {"!" -> "\[Not]", "&&" -> "\[And]", "||" -> "\[Or]"
     (*,"Nor"\[Rule] "\[Nor]","Nand"\[Rule] "\[UpArrow]","Xor"\[Rule] 
     "\[CirclePlus]","Xnor"->"\[CircleDot]","Implies"\[Rule] 
     "\[Implies]"*)
     }
   },
  StringReplace[ (expr // StandardForm // ToString),
   Join[rules, logicStrings]]
  ]
```

Key change is the use of "StandardForm". You can test this with inputs in `\[]` notation for variables or `Xor[a,b]` form.

---

Test:

```
h[Xor[a, b, Or[c, d]] && Xor[b, c]]
```

[image]

---

For creating logic truth tables:

1- `exprList` is the list of table entries; e.g.;

```
exprList = {a \[Implies] b, c, (a \[Implies] b) \[Implies] c, 
   d, ((a \[Implies] b) \[Implies] c) \[Implies] d};
```

2- From this, `BooleanVariables` will be extracted. These will form the however many variable columns that go before the first vertical divider. For our example:

```
vars = (BooleanVariables /@ exprList ) // Flatten // Union
```

> {a, b, c, d}

3- Now, table columns consist of the Boolean variables and the expressions, these are joined.

```
tableCols = vars~Join~exprList
```

> ```
> {a, b, c, d, 
>  a \[Implies] b, c, (a \[Implies] b) \[Implies] 
>   c, d, ((a \[Implies] b) \[Implies] c) \[Implies] d}
> ```

4- Variable go before the divider placed after `Length@vars`. Appropriate number of False values in a list will be spliced.

```
varDivs = ConstantArray[False, Length@vars]
```

> {False, False, False, False}

5- `hdr` is the utility function `h` applied to `tableCols` generating strings as required. 2^n rows are generated; and various dividers are put in place. A divider is placed at the end of the table. For standard logic courses "T T T" entries go first, (For circuits, usually "0 0 0" entries go first) so on line 3 `Reverse@dta` accomplishes that. At the end, you can add a rule to change 1/0 to T/F if you want or remove the `Boole` used in `dta`.

```
dta = Reverse[Boole[BooleanTable[tableCols]]];
hdr = h /@ tableCols
Grid[Prepend[Reverse@dta, hdr]
  , Dividers -> {
    {Splice[varDivs], True},
    {True, True}~Join~ConstantArray[False, 2^Length[vars] - 1]~
     Join~{True}
    }
  , Spacings -> {1, 1/2}
  , Alignment -> Center
  , FrameStyle -> Gray
  ] /. {0 -> F, 1 -> T}
```

[image]

---

For your original example:

[image]

---

I hope this turns out to be more useful than the original attempt.

---

**Original attempt**

Too long for a comment, but here is an attempt:

```
f[v_] := Module[
  {
   k = List @@ v,
   ch = Switch[v[[0]], 
     And, "\[And]",
     Or, "\[Or]",
     Nand, "\[Nand]",
     Nor, "\[Nor]",
     Xor, "\[Xor]",
     Xnor, "\[Xnor]",
     Implies, "\[Implies]"
     ],
   rules = { 
     "a" -> "P"
     , "b" -> "Q"
     , "c" -> "R"
     , "d" -> "S"
     , "e" -> "T"
     }
   },
  StringReplace[
   "(" <>
    StringJoin[Riffle[Riffle[ToString /@ k, ch], " "]] <>
    ")"
   , rules
   ]
  ]
```

---

Usage: `f` will return a string in standard logic notation for the args translated according to `rules`.

```
{f[Or[a, b]], f[And[a, b, c]], f[Xor[a, b, c, d]], f[Implies[a, b]]}
```

$$\{\text{(P $\lor $ Q)},\text{(P $\land $ Q $\land $ R)},\text{(P $\veebar $ Q $\veebar $ R $\veebar $ S)},\text{(P $\Rightarrow $ Q)}\}$$

Comment: Thank you, @Syed. - I will try to use this as a replacement for the hdr in the primary code: hdr = {
       "P", "Q", "(P \[Or] Q)", "\[Not](\[Not]P \[And] \[Not]Q)"
       };
I could not have imagined that this would be such a complicated function.

Comment: I was so caught up in writing this, I didn't pay attention to the `hdr` above. Try:  `expr1 = Not[And[Not[a], Not[b]]]` and then `StringReplace[
 ToString[expr1 /. {a -> "P", b -> "Q"}], {"a" -> "P", "b" -> "Q", 
  "&&" -> "\[And]", "!" -> "\[Not]"}]`. If it works, I will edit this into the answer.

Comment: Thank you !, I' am able to work on this again this afternoon. ( Europe )

Comment: It should be possible to convert a general Boolean expression to a "standard logic expression" somehow in Mathematica; but as I have discovered, I need to learn a lot more. For multilevel expressions, I still don't have a solution as it requires (perhaps) a recursive approach that I cannot quite pin down.

Comment: Thank you so very, very much @Syed. - Due to Christmas "pressures" I haven't been able to work much on any of my ( pet ) projects. Will come back to this.